# Getting error Failed to get master coverage in gitHub+jenkins+sonarqube integration

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

we are doing gitHub+Jenkins+Sonarqube integration, as part of this we want to publish the code coverage as comment in gitHub pull request.
We enabled the 'Use Sonar for master coverage' in Coverage status for GitHub Pull Requests and provided sonar url. 
 Project available in sonarQube. But build failed to get master coverage with following exception:

```
com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.SonarMasterCoverageRepository$SonarCoverageMeasureRetrievalException: failed to get coverage measure for sonar project account.cp.convert:savings - No results for path: $['component']['measures'][0]['value']
    at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.SonarMasterCoverageRepository.getCoverageMeasure(SonarMasterCoverageRepository.java:116)
    at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.SonarMasterCoverageRepository.get(SonarMasterCoverageRepository.java:67)
    at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.CompareCoverageAction.perform(CompareCoverageAction.java:138)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1835)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: No results for path: $['component']['measures'][0]['value']
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.EvaluationContextImpl.getValue(EvaluationContextImpl.java:133)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:187)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.read(JsonContext.java:164)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.read(JsonContext.java:151)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:502)
    at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.JsonUtils.findInJson(JsonUtils.java:7)
    at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.SonarMasterCoverageRepository.getCoverageMeasure(SonarMasterCoverageRepository.java:113)
[GitHub PR Status] master coverage: 0.0
[GitHub PR Status] collecting coverage...
[GitHub PR Status] build coverage: 0.22293408
[GitHub PR Status] Coverage 22% changed +22.29% vs master 0%
```

Comment posted as 22% vs master 0%

How to get master coverage from sonarqube?